# Getting unique Ids but not loose any data using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Given a table `sale` where `id` is not unique:

```
id  name     item   quantity
1   Darsh    shoes      5
2   Liyah    oil        1
2   Eiliyah  watch      1
3   Zakaria  notebook   2
3   Elliot   shirt      3
4   Reese    bag        1
```

I need to select all unique ids for a row and not loose any data(like for `id in (2,3)` where both name,item and quantity should be displayed in same row).Also there are maximum of 2 same `id` in `sale` table.

I tried using row_number() to get some unique pattern(s).
From this query :

```
Select a.id,a.name,a.item,a.quantity,b.name as name2,b.item as item2,b.quantity as quantity2
       ,row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.id) as f1
       ,row_number() over(partition by a.name order by a.id) as f2
from sale a inner join sale b on a.id = b.id
```

I got this

```
id  name    item    quantity  name2    item2    quantity2  f1   f2
1   Darsh   shoes     5       Darsh    shoes    5          1    1
2   Eiliyah watch     1       Liyah    oil      1          2    1
2   Eiliyah watch     1       Eiliyah  watch    1          4    2
3   Elliot  shirt     3       Zakaria  notebook 2          2    1
3   Elliot  shirt     3       Elliot   shirt    3          4    2
2   Liyah   oil       1       Eiliyah  watch    1          3    1
2   Liyah   oil       1       Liyah    oil      1          1    2
4   Reese   bag       1       Reese    bag      1          1    1
3   Zakaria notebook  2       Elliot   shirt    3          3    1
3   Zakaria notebook  2       Zakaria  notebook 2          1    2
```

Now here the problem,If I filter f1,f2 and use IIF for remove repetitive data using this query :

```
Select id,name,item,quantity
      ,iif(name = name2,NULL,name2) as name2
      ,iif(item = item2,NULL,item2) as item2
      ,iif(quantity = quantity2,NULL,quantity2) as quantity2
from (
  Select a.id,a.name,a.item,a.quantity,b.name as name2,b.item as item2,b.quantity as quantity2
         ,row_number() over(partition by a.id order by a.id) as f1
         ,row_number() over(partition by a.name order by a.id) as f2
  from sale a inner join sale b on a.id = b.id
  )t
where (f1=1 and f2=1) or(f1=3 and f2=1)
order by id
```

then `quantity2` is (null) in 2nd row as shown below.

```
id  name    item    quantity    name2   item2   quantity2
1   Darsh   shoes     5         NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Liyah   oil       1         Eiliyah watch   NULL
3   Zakaria notebook  2         Elliot  shirt   3
4   Reese   bag       1         NULL    NULL    NULL
```

So, there can be same `quantity` for different `item` and `name`.

Expected result:

```
id  name    item    quantity    name2   item2   quantity2
1   Darsh   shoes     5         NULL    NULL    NULL
2   Liyah   oil       1         Eiliyah watch   1
3   Zakaria notebook  2         Elliot  shirt   3
4   Reese   bag       1         NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation . . . if you know that there are at most two duplicates per id:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as name_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end) as item_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then quantity end) as quantity_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as name_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then item end) as item_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then quantity end) as quantity_2
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from sale s
     ) s
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected result .You can create temp(or Intermediate table) and as there are maximum of same two id ,then this can be your answer:

```
select *,row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as u_id into #test from sale
select * from (select * from #test where u_id=1) a
left join (select * from #test where u_id=2)b
on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: No problem,If this answer is relevant to you then can you please accept it ?